# Is it possible to pipe only on error?

Tags: command-line, pipe, error-handling

If there is any error then 2>&1 and pipe (|) to another program, otherwise do not 2>&1 and do not pipe

Comment: What is the use case? You can hack this together using a temporary file (to contain either the exit code or standard error), but otherwise you'll have to do something worse like running the command twice (assuming it's idempotent). Also, if there is no error there will typically be nothing on standard error anyway, and in that case usually the command after the pipe is going to output nothing.

Comment: Use case - Temporary file - could it be turned into an environment variable? ..."if there is no error..." -  that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Show a real use-case. It may help us see a solution. Abstract problems are not as easy to solve for some of us.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to run

```
main_program 2>&1 | filter_program
```

except that `filter_program` should only run if `main_program` returns a failure status.

The status of the program is not known until the program has finished executing. Therefore, to process the output only if the program fails, you need to save the output of the program while it's running, then once the program has finished, either run the output processing command or discard the output. Note that in this answer, I'll use “output” to mean the combined output from stdout and stderr; if you want to process stdout separately, extra work may be necessary.

If the output is small and is text-only, you can save the output and the return status in a shell variable. This doesn't work for binary data (data containing null bytes) because most shells don't support binary data in variables.

```
error_output=$(main_program 2>&1; echo ".$?")
error_status=${error_output##*.}
error_output=${error_output%.*}
if [ "$error_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  printf %s "$error_output" | filter_program
fi
```

If the output is potentially large or binary, save it to a temporary file.

```
output_file=$(mktemp)
main_program >"$output_file" 2>&1
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  filter_program <"$output_file"
fi
rm -f -- "$output_file"
```

(Omitted: code to remove the temporary file on a signal.)
(Replace `filter_program <"$output_file"` by `<"$output_file" cat | filter_program` if it's important that `filter_program`'s input comes from a pipe.)

---

If the main program only produces output on failures, you can start the filter as soon as it produces output, rather than wait for the exit status. The [`ifne`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/moreutils/ifne.1.en.html) utility from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) is convenient for that.

```
main_program 2>&1 | ifne filter_program
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you be looking for [named pipes](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156)? Something like this:

```
## Create a named pipe
$ mkfifo errorPipe

## In another shell session, launch whatever program you want to pipe the
## error to, telling it to read from errorPipe
$ errorCommand < errorPipe

##$ wc -l errorPipe
```

1 errorPipe
Run your program, redirecting its stderr to the named pipe
$ yourCommand 2> errorPipe

This way, only the error will be piped to `errorCommand`. To illustrate:

```
$ mkfifo errorPipe
$ wc -l < errorPipe ## this will hang until I write something to errorPipe
```

Now, I open another terminal and run:

```
$  perl -le 'sleep(2); 
            print "this is stdout"; 
            sleep(2); 
            print STDERR "this is stderr"' 2>errorPipe  
this is stdout
```

After 2 seconds, I will see `this is stdout` printed in the current terminal. Meanwhile, the `wc` process I had started in the other terminal will exit and print its results:

```
$ wc -l errorPipe 
1 errorPipe
```